# Blank screen when using tiled wmts in Geoserver and Openlayers

Tags: geoserver, openlayers, wmts

I am currently following the book GeoServer beginners guide (ISBN: 978-1-78829-737-0). I am on chapter 8 and have been using the following code sample from the book:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <title>WMTS</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://openlayers.org/en/v4.2.0/css/ol.css" type="text/css">
    <script src="https://openlayers.org/en/v4.2.0/build/ol.js"></script>
    <style type="text/css">
      html { height: 100% }
      body { 
        height: 100%; 
        margin: 20px; 
        }
      .map {
        border: 1px solid black;
        width: 800px;
        height: 550px;
        }  
    </style>
  </head>
  <body>
    <div id="map" class="map"></div>
    <script>
      var projection = ol.proj.get('EPSG:4326');
      var projectionExtent = projection.getExtent();
      var matrixIds = new Array(22);
      for (var z = 0; z < 22; ++z) {
        matrixIds[z] = "EPSG:4326:" + z;
      }
      var resolutions = [
            0.703125, 0.3515625, 0.17578125, 0.087890625,
            0.0439453125, 0.02197265625, 0.010986328125,
            0.0054931640625, 0.00274658203125, 0.001373291015625,
            6.866455078125E-4, 3.4332275390625E-4, 1.71661376953125E-4,
            8.58306884765625E-5, 4.291534423828125E-5, 2.1457672119140625E-5,
              1.0728836059570312E-5, 5.364418029785156E-6, 2.682209014892578E-6,
            1.341104507446289E-6, 6.705522537231445E-7, 3.3527612686157227E-7
      ];

      var map = new ol.Map({
        layers: [
          new ol.layer.Tile({
            opacity: 0.7,
            source: new ol.source.WMTS({
              url: 'http://localhost:8080/geoserver/gwc/service/wmts',
              layer: 'Packt:NaturalEarthCountries',
              matrixSet: 'EPSG:4326',
              format: 'image/png',
              projection: projection,
              tileGrid: new ol.tilegrid.WMTS({
                origin: ol.extent.getTopLeft(projectionExtent),
                resolutions: resolutions,
                matrixIds: matrixIds
              })
            })
          })
        ],
        target: 'map',
        view: new ol.View({
          projection: projection,
          center: [10, 40],
          zoom: 4
        })
      });
    </script>
  </body>
</html>
```

When checking the tile layers in geoserver I am able to preview them, however when viewing the output of this code in a web browser, I just get a blank screen. Other resources suggest putting the name of my workspace (packt) in the url:

so it would be:

```
url: 'http://localhost:8080/geoserver/gwc/Packt/service/wmts',
```

however this does not work either.
what should the URL be or is the problem somewhere else?

Comment: are you sure that Packt has a capital P? workspace names are case sensitive. Does the log file show anything?

Comment: Sorry Ian, I didn't see your comment. Packt is with a capital P. My log is showing geoserver fell back to embedded data at some point this morning. But the computrer has been reset since, with no more logs.

Comment: I checked example code at GitHub: https://github.com/PacktPublishing/GeoServer-Beginners-Guide-Second-Edition. Code is exact copy from example, so it should work (or not, one never knows with this examples).

Comment: ok. I'l keep checking and see if I can see what I did wrong.

Answer (score 1):

What is wrong are references to Open Layers libraries which do not exist any more.

This should work (see https://openlayers.org/en/latest/doc/quickstart.html):

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdn.rawgit.com/openlayers/openlayers.github.io/master/en/v5.3.0/css/ol.css" type="text/css">
<script src="https://cdn.rawgit.com/openlayers/openlayers.github.io/master/en/v5.3.0/build/ol.js"></script>
```

Comment: If older versions are needed for backward compatibility they are still available via https://cdnjs.com/libraries/openlayers/

Comment: I've changed to the latest libraries, I have also downloaded openlayers 5 and pulled the stylesheet and javascript files from that. I'm still getting the same results even though it works with none wmts files.

Comment: I tried your code with OSM source and it works. There must be something wrong with you WMTS source definition. What about trying suggestion from Ian Turton?

Comment: my Bad, I didn't see that suggestion. My logfile shows it fell back to embedded data about 10:30. But the computer has been restarted since then with no other logs.

Comment: 2019-04-12 10:38:53,513 INFO [geoserver.platform] - Falling back to embedded     data directory: /opt/apache-tomcat-8.5.39/webapps/geoserver/data
  2 2019-04-12 10:38:53,609 INFO [geoserver.platform] - Falling back to embedded     data directory: /opt/apache-tomcat-8.5.39/webapps/geoserver/data
  3 2019-04-12 10:38:59,904 INFO [org.geoserver] - GeoServer configuration lock     is enabled
  4 2019-04-12 10:39:02,074 INFO [org.geoserver] - Loaded style 'poi'
  5 2019-04-12 10:39:02,075 INFO [org.geoserver] - Loaded style 'simple_roads'

Comment: What you get with `GetCapabilities` request? Check if you have correct parameters in your WMTS source definition.